# py.test use -m AS WELL as directory path in command

Tags: python, django, bash, pytest

I'd like to only run selenium tests in my test suite, in addition to filtering it down to only run tests in a specific file/folder. It seems like I should be able to accomplish this with the `-m` option, and the path positional argument. Furthermore, I'm doing this in a bash script.

So for example, I tried something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# ...some logic here for determining `EXTRA` arg
EXTRA = "not selenium"
py.test -m $EXTRA -v -s --tb=long --no-flaky-report ~/project/mytests/test_blerg.py
```

And then my test looks like this (still using xunit-style classes):

```
@pytest.mark.selenium
class BaseTest(UnitTest):
    pass

class ChildTest(BaseTest):

    def test_first_case(self):
        pass
```

When I run the py.test command as I described above, I get this:

```
============================================================================ no tests ran in 0.01 seconds ============================================================================
ERROR: file not found: selenium"
```

Not completely sure why this doesn't work. I'll try manually overriding `pytest_runtest_setup()`, but I'm feel like I should be able to accomplish what I want without doing that. Also, just FYI, this **is** a django project, using `Django==1.8.7` and `pytest-django==2.9.1`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. This has nothing to do with `py.test` itself. I had an error in how I was calling the `py.test` command in my bash script. The amended command looks like this:

```
py.test -m "$EXTRA" -v -s --tb=long --no-flaky-report ~/project/mytests/test_blerg.py
```

Works as expected!